# Не отображается микросервис на другом сервере

Tags: java, docker, spring-boot, микросервисы

Возникла проблема с переходом с монолитного проекта на ммикросервисную архитектуру. Есть несколько сервисов которые будут распологаться на одном сервре и несколько других на другом. Пытаюсь реализовать это, но никак не получается. Сам dashboad работает некорректно. Сервисы которые были отключены отображатся UP. Это достаточно странно, поскольку при тестировании было все корректно. Как только начали использовать докер, неисправность возникла. Как правильно настроить интеграцию микросервисов в докере и еще к тому же на нескольких серверах?

Вот все сервисы:

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  eureka-server:
    build:
      context: ./eureka-server
    restart: always
    environment:
      DEBUG_LEVEL: INFO
    ports:
      - 8761:8761
    volumes:
      - /temp/eureka-server/logs:/usr/app/eureka-server/logs

  gateway-service:
    build:
      context: ./gateway-service
    restart: always
    environment:
      DEBUG_LEVEL: INFO
      EUREKA_URI: http://eureka-server:8761/eureka
    ports:
      - 8762:8762
    volumes:
      - /temp/gateway-service/logs:/usr/app/gateway-service/logs
    depends_on:
      - eureka-server

  microservice-location:
    build:
      context: ./microservice-location
    restart: always
    environment:
      DB_URL: file:/usr/app/h2/microservice_location
      DB_USER: ****
      DB_PASSWORD: *******
      DEBUG_LEVEL: INFO
      EUREKA_URI: http://eureka-server:8761/eureka
    volumes:
      - /temp/microservice-location/h2:/usr/app/h2/
      - /temp/microservice-location/logs:/usr/app/microservice-location/logs
    depends_on:
      - eureka-server

  microservice-profession:
    build:
      context: ./microservice-profession
    restart: always
    environment:
      DB_URL: file:/usr/app/h2/microservice_profession
      DB_USER: ******
      DB_PASSWORD: ******
      DEBUG_LEVEL: INFO
      EUREKA_URI: http://eureka-server:8761/eureka
    volumes:
      - /temp/microservice-profession/h2:/usr/app/h2/
      - /temp/microservice-profession/logs:/usr/app/microservice-profession/logs
    depends_on:
      - eureka-server

  microservice-education:
    build:
      context: ./microservice-education
    restart: always
    environment:
      DB_URL: file:/usr/app/h2/microservice_education
      DB_USER: ************          DB_PASSWORD: *******
      DEBUG_LEVEL: INFO
      EUREKA_URI: http://eureka-server:8761/eureka
    volumes:
      - /temp/microservice-education/h2:/usr/app/h2/
      - /temp/microservice-education/logs:/usr/app/microservice-education/logs
    depends_on:
      - eureka-server

  microservice-money:
    build:
      context: ./microservice-money
    restart: always
    environment:
      DB_URL: file:/usr/app/h2/microservice_money
      DB_USER: ***************
      DB_PASSWORD: **************
      DEBUG_LEVEL: INFO
      EUREKA_URI: http://eureka-server:8761/eureka
    volumes:
      - /temp/microservice-money/h2:/usr/app/h2/
      - /temp/microservice-money/logs:/usr/app/microservice-money/logs
    depends_on:
      - eureka-server

  microservice-company:
    build:
      context: ./microservice-company
    restart: always
    environment:
      DB_HOST: db
      DB_PORT: 3306
      DB_NAME: microservice_company
      DB_USER: ****************
      DB_PASSWORD: **************************
      DEBUG_LEVEL: INFO
      EUREKA_URI: http://eureka-server:8761/eureka
    volumes:
      - /temp/microservice-company/logs:/usr/app/microservice-company/logs
    depends_on:
      - eureka-server

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8002:8080

  db:
    image: mysql:8.0.17
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: *********************
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - /temp/mysql01:/var/lib/mysql
    security_opt:
      - seccomp:unconfined

  microservice-resume:
    build:
      context: ./microservice-resume
    restart: always
    environment:
      DB_HOST: db
      DB_PORT: 3306
      DB_NAME: microservice_resume
      DB_USER: ******************
      DB_PASSWORD: *********************
      DEBUG_LEVEL: INFO
      EUREKA_URI: http://eureka-server:8761/eureka
    volumes:
      - /temp/microservice-resume/logs:/usr/app/microservice-resume/logs
    depends_on:
      - eureka-server

  microservice-vacancy:
    build:
      context: ./microservice-vacancy
    restart: always
    environment:
      DB_HOST: db
      DB_PORT: 3306
      DB_NAME: microservice_vacancy
      DB_USER: *******
      DB_PASSWORD: *******
      DEBUG_LEVEL: INFO
      EUREKA_URI: http://eureka-server:8761/eureka
    volumes:
      - /temp/microservice-vacancy/logs:/usr/app/microservice-vacancy/logs
    depends_on:
      - eureka-server
```

Comment: так может вам firewall режет трафик?

Comment: @tym32167 не думаю что в трафике дело. на одном сервере можно все настроить. Но на двух если настривать сервисы не видят друг друга

Comment: @tym32167 пробовал с рабочего компа подключить сервис, но результат тот же

Comment: попробуйте пробросить порты в брандмауэре, если у вас винда, или совсем его выключить, проверить связь, и включить обратно.

Comment: @tym32167 думаю вполне вероятно что нужно настроить 8761 порт на сервере линукса. Как проверю отпишу.

Comment: @tym32167 проблема была не в файрволах. у docker-compose по умолчанию отдельная сеть от хоста. Поэтому не мог нормально подключить сервисы с разных хостов.

Comment: Спасибо что отписались, это полезно знать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том что docker-compose по умолчанию использует собственную сеть. (отдельную от сети хоста). Чтобы исправить это нужно было добавить `network_mode: host`. Подробнее об этом можно прочитать тут: https://docs.docker.com/network/

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  eureka-server:
    hostname: localhost
    network_mode: host
    build:
      context: ./eureka-server
    restart: always
    environment:
      DEBUG_LEVEL: INFO
    ports:
      - 8761:8761
    volumes:
      - /temp/eureka-server/logs:/usr/app/eureka-server/logs

  gateway-service:
    hostname: localhost
    network_mode: host
    build:
      context: ./gateway-service
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8762:8762
    volumes:
      - /temp/gateway-service/logs:/usr/app/gateway-service/logs
```